# Using Opclabs QuickOPC Controls

Tags: c#, visual-studio, winforms, opc

I installed `OpcLabs.QuickOpc` and `OpcLabs.QuickOpc.Forms` libraries in my project. But when I drag a quickopc tool on the form, it shows an error:

> Error: Failed to create toolboxitem of type: OpcLabs.EasyOpc.Toolbox.FormsToolboxItem, OpcLabs.EasyOpcVSToolbox, Version=5.60.107.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=6faddca41dacb409

[image: Error Image]

Can someone help? I need to use OpcBrowseControl.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Answered here: [Using Opclabs QuickOPC Controls via C# (WinForms)](https://www.opclabs.com/forum/ua-general/3469-using-opclabs-quickopc-controls-via-c-winforms#11158)

Quote:

> In order to use Visual Studio integration features of QuickOPC, including Toolbox items, you must install QuickOPC using the standalone installation program ...

Comment: This is the best good morning news I've ever heard! This post is also mine :). Thank you again.